# VBA hangs when opening Excel files

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which loops through a list of Excel filepaths. The macro will read each path, open the workbook, copy/pull data out of each workbook and then pastevalues the data into a central workbook. There are about 2000 filepaths.

After a while (maybe after it has looped through the first 70 or so filepaths), Excel hangs. It shows the "Downloading" message box that you get when opening a file. If I click cancel on the msg box, the workbook opens and the macro continues as normal.

I would have to sit here for 1000s of filepaths. Why does Excel get stuck here? Is there a way around it?

This message box does not happen on every Workbooks.Open instance, just after every few.

Example of the code:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filepaths")
    For i = firstrow To lastrow
        SourceFile = .Cells(i, 1).Value
        Workbooks.Open SourceFile, ReadOnly:=True 
        Set MyFile = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
        ' ..more code..........
        ' ..more code..........
        ' ..more code..........
        MyFile.close
    Next i
End With
```

Thanks for the comments. These are both good points (and are both solutions I believe I have tried in the past). But just to check, I modified my Workbooks.Open line:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks.Open SourceFile, ReadOnly:=True, UpdateLinks:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

But the message box is still popping up.

What's weird is when I step thru line by line, after I step past the `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` line, when I hover over the "Application.DisplayAlerts" variable, it still says true?

Comment: Maybe turning off `Application.DisplayAlerts` (and `ScreenUpdating` while you are at it)  would help.

Comment: Couldn't you `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`?

Comment: Maybe invalid external Links in some of the workbooks?

Comment: too @CharlesWilliams point, set `UpdateLinks:=False` in UpdateLinks argument of Workbook.Open() event.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman thanks guys, please see my edit to my original post

Comment: Another maybe.... `Set MyFile = Workbooks.Open SourceFile, ReadOnly:=True`.  I'm thinking `Set MyFile = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)` get confused with the `Workbooks.Count` number?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I don't think your suggested line of code is valid... But I did try changing to MyFile = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name), but that is not working either. And just to be clear, the "hang up msg box" is happening when I run the "Workbooks.Open..." line of code.

Comment: Apologies, you're correct - it should be `Set MyFile = Workbooks.Open (SourceFile, ReadOnly:=True)` - I forgot the brackets.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook thank you. I have tried what you suggested. I still get the hanging Downloading message... I am starting to think there is no way around this...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are trying to open a file from a shared drive and that is why it is showing you the "**Downloading**" message box. This happens sometimes.

`Application.DisplayAlerts = False` in such scenario will not help. Nor will `ReadOnly:=True, UpdateLinks:=False` help.

Try this code (**Untested**)

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filepaths")
    For i = firstrow To lastrow
        SourceFile = .Cells(i, 1).Value

        '~~> Check for network path and use sendkeys
        '~~> to close the downloading window
        If InStr(1, SourceFile, "\\") Then _
        Application.SendKeys "~", True

        Workbooks.Open SourceFile, ReadOnly:=True

        Set MyFile = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
        '..more code..........
        '..more code..........
        '..more code..........
        MyFile.Close
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: yes, it is from a shared drive. However, all the paths are mapped drives (the O:\ drive) on all the users PCs. I was playing around with the SendKeys code already (but can't say that I fully understand it). Anyway. the SendKeys code I had been playing around with does seem to be working better. But I do seem to still be getting the occasional "Downloading" msg box hang up, but just not as often...

Comment: replace `"\\"` with `"O:\"`

Comment: thanks. This is causing weird things to happen... like the macro occasionally stopping and opening the debug window on the Workbooks.Open line, or the macro inserting additional blank rows after the application.sendkeys line or after the workbooks.open line...

Comment: Just wanted to point out, I'm in a network share but the solution here would not work. I just enabled the errors and the visibility of the new application (I'm oppening the new workbooks in a diferent instance because I do not want to see a thing so I'm making the new excel app invisible) and found out that someone had renamed the file so the open command was giving an error that I could not see